# Rails 4 is adding controller name to the asset url which causes 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am wondering why Rails 4 is adding the controller name to the asset request when I click on a controller specific page.  For example, instead of this url (which is accurate): /assets/jqBootstrapValidation.js

It's generating this url (causing a 404 error):  /controllername/assets/jqBootstrapValidation.js

It's happening for all js and css files I have manually added to the app/assets directories. Seems like the asset request is getting confused and adding the current directory name to the request but I don't know how to fix it (the assets are in the correct directory).

How do I remove the controller name from the asset request? Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Comment: This happens when the asset pipeline can't locate the asset. You are probably not using the rails helpers to include your assets.

Comment: Please post a snippet of code from where you are including your asset

Comment: I am using the out of the box references to assets:  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Comment: Ok, so my next guess would be that the files aren't saved in the appropriate directory. What are the paths (starting from `app/`)

Comment: have you tried calling your file inside app/asset/js/Application.js file like: //jqBootstrapValidation

Comment: The files are saved in the app/assets/javascript directory and css files are stored in the app/assets/stylesheets directory. I have verified they are there by manually going to app/assets/filename and they load fine.

Comment: I tried calling the files from inside app/asset/js/Application.js but that still resulted in the 404 error.

Comment: @thenextmogul I dont know exactly but you mentioned above that this BootstrapValidation.js file is inside dir. asset/ where as it is suppose to be in js/ if i am not wrong

Comment: Strange, could you post your application config file?

Comment: because Appilication.js with //tree command call all the js files inside js/ dir. not outside the js/ dir.

Comment: @Abhinay - The file is located in the javascript directory (assets/javascript/filename) but the URL generated when the page loads is supposed to be assets/filename.  Instead, it's generating controllername/assets/filename.

Comment: can you also post your application.js file here ?